# Use mmap to map a single file multiple times. Will the changes be applied to all locations?

Tags: c, mmap

I am reading the source code of a paper. Mmap is used here.
There is a 4kB page called 4kb.file. First, I use mmap to map this file multiple times.

```
ret = mmap((void *) target, PAGE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FILE, fd, 0);
```

`target` is the starting address of the mapping I set. Use different `target` variable and call the above instruction multiple times. Is this file mapped to multiple locations in memory? Suppose that the return values of the above function executed multiple times are ret1, ret2, ret3, and ret4. Now I modify the content pointed to by ret1, will the positions of ret2, ret3... change (the same file is mapped to a different location)?

Is the first parameter in mmap, which is the target above, a virtual address? The source code always starts with 0x300000000000ULL. Does this number have any special meaning?
Thanks

Comment: You will probably have better luck passing `NULL` as the first argument. The kernel will select the virtual address [to be different]. If `mmap` does _not_ complain, doing `ret1 = mmap(0x3000000,...); ret2 = mmap(0x3000000,...);` will be _bad_. You should _edit_ your question and post more of your source code as the single line and description aren't enough for a reasonable answer.

Comment: It is not target=0x300000000000ULL. The above said that different targets are used. But in the source code, target=0x300000000000ULL+random number (random number that meets certain conditions). The code is https://github.com/Arsalaan-Hameed/CS665-TLBLEED/blob/master/src/dtlb_latency.c

Comment: You are mapping the _same_ part of the file to different addresses in application memory [these _are_ virtual/logical addresses]. In this case, _all_ mappings point to the first 4096 bytes of the file starting at byte 0 of the file. Thus, they will point to the same physical page in memory. But, the file (and, therefore, the resident page) is the _backing store_ for the mapping. It is not guaranteed to be updated until the file is unmapped. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: This is the code for a top conference paper. I didn't write it. I am figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [msync()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) and especially the **MS_INVALIDATE** flag :

> msync()  flushes  changes  made to the in-core copy of a file that was mapped into memory using mmap(2) back to the filesystem.
> MS_INVALIDATE
> Asks to invalidate other mappings of the same file (so that they can be updated with the fresh values just written).